# Can I share functions between main app and web workers?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, web-worker

I have a React app that involves some lengthy processing. I have 30 charts to display and need to calculate the data for each one.

The code to do these calculations is fairly complex.

I'd like a web worker to do the initial calculations for all 30 (to keep app responsive when first loaded).

However, I also need to recalculate each change on demand---if someone changes a chart parameters. This can block as it's fast enough.

I have the code for all the updates, but, I've realised I can't call that from the web worker. But, if I put all that code in the web worker, then I can't call it from my main app.

The chart calcs share a lot of common code. I could build a web worker for each chart, but then could I share a single function between them? It looks like I have to have the function defined *inside* the web worker.

Feels like I must be confused here as surely one doesn't need to write common code inside each web worker. Is there a way I can *inject* the code into the web worker?

Comment: Just put the respective function in a separate file and load it from both the main thread as well as from the worker. Then your function should be available in both. (Aside: you have no DOM access from within the worker, so you really can just manipulate the data itself, but not render it from there)

Comment: can you please share minimal code for better understanding ?